# I need to stop a execution of a command and start the same comma every x interval of time in terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, schedule, scheduler, gnome-schedule

I need to stop execution of a running java script in terminal and start the same execution at every x interval of time in terminal. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `/usr/bin/timeout` is the tool to use. See `man timeout`. Here is an example, from one of my nightly `cron` jobs, you can wrap yours in a `while true ; do` loop:

```
TO_KILL="45m"           # timeout (kill -KILL) for hpodder
TO_HUP="42m"            # timeout (kill -HUP) for hpodder. Makes sense only if it is less than $TO_KILL
# ...
timeout -k $TO_KILL -s HUP $TO_HUP hpodder  update
```

This will run the `hpodder update` until it finishes, or 42 minutes have passed, when it will be sent (see `man 7 signal`) a `HUP` signal. If `hpodder update` is still running after 45 minutes (3 minutes after the `HUP` was sent), it will be sent the uncatchable `KILL` signal, and will be terminated.